# How to choose the n-th element that is placed after h1 element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to select the 4th div element that is placed after h1 element, I think that my way is not a professional way, Is there a specified selector in css for things like that? Note that I have to do it without adding an id or class attributes to the div.

```
h1+div+div+div+div{
background-color:red; 
}

<h1>css</h1>

<div>just some text here,</div><hr>
<div>just some text here,</div><hr>
<div>just some text here,</div><hr>
<div>just some text here,</div><hr>
<div>just some text here,</div><hr>
```

Comment: is hr is always there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select it using **`nth-of-type`** and the **`subsequent sibling combinator`** to select the 4th `div` after the `h1` like this:

```
h1~div:nth-of-type(4) {
    background-color:red;
}
```

The `~` in css is called the **subsequent sibling combinator** which allows you to select the second element type where the first and second element type share a parent and the first element precedes the second element type in the document.

---

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/crq43gs5/

---

In cases where you're sure there aren't any `hr` tags or other elements in between your `divs`, you can use `nth-child` instead but have to use 5 instead of 4 since the ~ counts the h1 tag too. It'll look something like this:

```
h1~div:nth-child(5) {
    background-color:red;
}
```

---

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/crq43gs5/1/

Comment: But it's not the 4th child in the page, I need to select the fourth div element specifically after the h1 element

Comment: Correct, is like the 8th element,
you nth child will place you in the nth child of the parent, so if you want to use nth child correctly you'll need to place your divs inside another container, and you'll want to use classes

Comment: @Marc and Mike Answer updated with jsfiddle :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Professional way :

add a class to that div, and select by the class

```
 .forthDiv{
       background-color:red; 
 }

 <div class="forthDiv">sometext</div>
```

the non professional, sometimes required way :

```
 div:nth-of-type(4){
 background-color:red; 
 }
```

Comment: I need to do it without adding a class, and it's not the 4th child in my page, It's the 4th div that is placed after the h1 element

Comment: sorry, you have to use  div:nth-of-type